# Connected components of topological space (X,T) where X={a,b,c} and T={$\emptyset$,{c},{a,b},X}

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Here I know first I need to know the connected subsets of X, then I'll choose maximal out of them. I need to confirm if the set A={a,c} is connect here or not. According to me it is connected because there is no proper non trivial subset in X intersection A which is both open and close

Comment: The notation for the empty set is $\emptyset$ (\emptyset) or $\varnothing$ (\varnothing), not $\phi$ (\phi) and certainly not "phi".

Comment: @AlexKruckman $\Phi$ is used in a lot of Russian texts, for $\emptyset$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sure, and I would make the same comment to the authors of those texts :)

Answer (score 2):

In the subspace topology of $A=\{a,c\}$ we have open subsets $A\cap U$ where $U$ is open in $X$. But then $\{c\} = A \cap \{c\}$ is open in $A$, and so is $\{a\} = A\cap \{a,b\}$. Since $\{a\}$ and $\{c\}$ are non-empty, disjoint and open, the fact that

$$ A= \{a,c\} = \{a\} \cup \{c\}$$

shows that $A$ is not connected.

The connected components of $X$ are $X_1 = \{a,b\}$ and $X_2 = \{c\}$, as these cannot be written as union of non-empty open and disjoint subsets.